# Display Angular 6 mat-card sourced by Firebase Data in random order on Page Load/Refresh

Tags: angular, random, mat-card

I display data from firebase. I want to show my cards in random order when I change the value of a form or refresh the page. It is possible?

Here's my Component Template:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let geoToDisplay  of geosToDisplay | async">
  <ng-container *ngIf="toppings2.value.includes(geoToDisplay.esSos)">
    <ng-container *ngIf="toppings.value.includes(geoToDisplay.typeSos)">
      <div class="col">
        <mat-card>BLABLA
        </mat-card>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
setInterval(() => {
    this.randomCard = this.geosToDisplay[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.geosToDisplay.length)]; // this'll get the random value depending on your array length
  }, 30000);
```

and bind it as,

```
 <mat-card >{{randomCard}}</mat-card>
```